# jQuery parents has both classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an if statement for `<a>` tags that have ***two*** classes. I've successfully implemented the following to check for one class:

```
if ($("a").parents().hasClass("class1")) {
                // do something...
            }
```

But how do you look for an element that has ***two*** classes, for example an element that had `class1` ***and*** `class2?` I know in CSS it would be `.class1.class2{}`, but not sure how in JavaScript?

Comment: you can use .is() instead of .hasClass(). try like this if ($("a").parents().is(".class1, .class2")) {}

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that appears to be grabbing both elements with just "class 1" or just "class 2" -- I was looking to get just elements with both classes

Comment: oh. my bad. then @troyrmeyer's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
alert($('#b2').hasClass('c1 c2 c3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="b2" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name." name="name" maxlength="300" class="c1 c2 c3" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `.is()` method.

```
// or any selector you want to check against.
if ($("a").parents().is(".class1.class2")) { 
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same methods, another way to do this would be with a double ampersand "&&":

```
if (($("a").parents().hasClass("class1")) && ($("a").parents().hasClass("class2"))) {
            // do something...
        }
```

It's a bit more code than previous examples, but it should be a good fail-safe!